# Unable to build gem5 in MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, gem5

I am receiving this error message when I run `scons build/ALPHA/gem5.opt`
I have followed all the steps listed on gem5 website.

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "PyTrafficGen::start(pybind11::object)", referenced from:
      module_init(pybind11::module&) in lib.o.partial
  "typeinfo for PyTrafficGen", referenced from:
      pybind11::detail::type_caster_base<PyTrafficGen>::cast(PyTrafficGen const*, pybind11::return_value_policy, pybind11::handle) in lib.o.partial
      pybind11::class_<PyTrafficGen, BaseTrafficGen, std::__1::unique_ptr<PyTrafficGen, pybind11::nodelete> >::class_<>(pybind11::handle, char const*) in lib.o.partial
      pybind11::class_<PyTrafficGen, BaseTrafficGen, std::__1::unique_ptr<PyTrafficGen, pybind11::nodelete> >::init_instance(pybind11::detail::instance*, void const*) in lib.o.partial
      __ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yE_S6_JSL_yEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS_ in lib.o.partial
      __ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS_ in lib.o.partial
      __ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyjjjjjjEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS_ in lib.o.partial
      __ZZN8pybind1112cpp_function10initializeIZNS0_C1INSt3__110shared_ptrI7BaseGenEE12PyTrafficGenJyyyyyyhyjjjjjjjEJNS_4nameENS_9is_methodENS_7siblingEEEEMT0_FT_DpT1_EDpRKT2_EUlPS7_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjjE_S6_JSL_yyyyyyhyjjjjjjjEJS8_S9_SA_EEEvOSC_PFSB_SE_ESK_ENKUlRNS_6detail13function_callEE_clESS_ in lib.o.partial
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [build/ALPHA/gem5.opt] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: What is your GCC / clang version? You should likely raise this on the mailing list.

Comment: clang -v    
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix